# внутреняя память Андроид

Tags: android, файловая-система, права

разбиралась с файловой системой `андройда` и не нашла способ получит права для доступа к внутренней памяти устройства. и я так поняла что даже у владельца устройства права `root` не имеются. но однако есть приложения позволяющие посмотреть файловую систему и поиграться с папками. как это возможно реализовать в приложении?

Comment: Просматривать каталоги (не все, конечно) пока ещё можно: `File rootDir = new File("/");` (это корень файловой системы устройства) и дальше по иерархии через `listFiles()`. Только не факт, что на свежих версиях системы это будет работать. Хотя что вы понимаете под *внутренней памятью устройства* - то, что файл менеджеры называют типа "Память телефона" или системные папки?

Comment: системные папки

Comment: я так поняла что есть первичная внешняя память это то куда скачиваются файлы картинки и в общем память вшитая в телефон,вторичная внешняя это съемная карта, и внутренняя там системные папки и папки других приложений не доступных моему

Comment: но при этом тот же Root Brawser  позволяет смотреть и изменять системные и папки в приложениях. значит все же можно добраться но как не понятно или через что? чтоб к внешней получить надо в манифесте прописать запрос  и на яве путь прописать. а здесь как не понятно

Comment: если я ошиблась в чем то, поправьте

Comment: Всё примерно так, кроме того, что много телефонов путают первичную и вторичную. На нерутированном аппарате читать файлы других приложений во внутренней памяти нельзя, но кроме внутренней памяти файлы пишут и во внешнюю - вот там, запросив `READ/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` можно поковыряться и к системным папкам можно попасть с тем же разрешением как я показал в первом комменте (только не все будут открываться). Но такую возможность скоро уберут, вроде уже в Android 10.

Comment: что ж они так гайки закручивают разработчикам.... За информацию спасибо

Comment: и правильно делают, вы просто не представляете сколько вреда это бы нанесло

Comment: Style-7 нет случайно книжек или статеек которые помогли бы понять?